# user.config not generated in local app data

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, app-config

For a c sharp WPF application. The user.config file I would expect to be generated in :
`\Users\username\AppData\Local\AssemblyCompany\AssemblyProduct\Assemblyproduct.exe_Url_asdf2345sf\version\user.config`.

But for some reason no such file is generated when running the application from visual studio 2012(the application is build under x86 platform and target framework .NET Framework 4). Does anyone know why this might happen?

Comment: Is the real question that you're looking for it and want to move it? Or do you really just want to know **why** it isnt there?

Comment: I want to know why it isn't there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually its under `\Users\username\AppData\Local\AssemblyCompany\Assemblyproduct.exe_Url_asdf2345sf\version\user.config`, there is no `\AssemblyProduct\`.

However it only gets generated after your application performs a `Settings.Default.Save();` otherwise defaults are picked up from your normal `Settings.Default`

Comment: Ok. But it's not under the path you posted either.

Comment: Has your application performed a `Settings.Default.Save()` ?

Comment: By the way, you can always use [Process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to watch where the file is being saved

Comment: thanks. I expected that the user.config file and the folder to be created when running the application. Apparently it is created when calling Settings.Default.Save()